# 500.19 error with IIS7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

I am getting the following error, even after I unlock my website. Any reasons?

HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

```
Module         CustomErrorModule
Notification   SendResponse
Handler        StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070021
Config Error   Lock violation
Config File    \\?\C:\Web\En\web.config

<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultPath="/Oops.aspx" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
<clear></clear>
```

I have done the following in applicationHost.config

```
<location path="mysite.net" overrideMode="Allow">
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers />
        <httpErrors />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar `Lock violation` error due to `defaultPath`. The [following](http://forums.iis.net/p/1159721/1959812.aspx) fixed it for me:

> The only thing that it works is to go and remove manually
>   "defaultPath" from "lockAttributes" attribute of xml node    in the
>   file  %windir%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

You'll have to decide for yourself whether editing `applicationHost.config` is too dirty.

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Mysteriously, while troubleshooting this on our dev/staging servers, and editing web.config on my local copy, this actually got *added* to my local copy of applicationhost.config (used by IIS Express) and the problem started appearing when debugging in Visual Studio. You can get to the local applicationhost.config from the IIS Express tray icon.

Comment: Also; on the web server you must use notepad to make the edits.

Answer (score 4):

I edited the applicationHost.config but was still getting the error.

Completely forgot that after you edit applicationHost.config, you have to restart IIS.

Answer (score 3):

As per [my answer to this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25698296/834431);

Try unlocking the relevant IIS configuration settings at server level, as follows:

1. Open **IIS Manager**
2. **Select the server** in the Connections pane
3. Open **Configuration Editor** in the main pane
4. In the Sections drop down, select the section to unlock, e.g. **system.webServer > defaultPath**
5. Click **Unlock Attribute** in the right pane
6. Repeat for any other settings which you need to unlock
7. Restart IIS (optional) - Select the server in the Conncetions pane, click Restart in the Actions pane

Comment: @AtLeastTheresToast are you able to elaborate on why it doesn't work on IIS 10 (I've not tested) and are you able to suggest an alternative solution for those on IIS 10?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this before and it had something to do with a security setup. Check the web application folder permissions and make sure the following users and groups are included "ASPNET", "IIS_IUSRS", "IUSR".

Don't know if this will work for you or not, but worth a try I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem by doing this:

1. Click "Start button"
2. In the search box, enter "Turn windows features on or off"
3. In the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"
4. Click: "World Wide Web Services"
5. Click: "Application Development Features"
6. Check (enable) the features. I checked all but CGI.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message after sharing my folder with a coworker.
The folder had a lock on it (in Windows explorer).
I had to release the lock (by granting a permission to all authenticated users, for further instructions view https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17117/remove-the-lock-icon-from-a-folder-in-windows-7/).
Once the lock has been removed, the error disappeared.