# HTTP Error 500.19 and error code : 0x80070021

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I have a simple webAPI build by Visual Studio 2013. It works well when I run it from VS13 but when I copy the project in local IIS it gives me the following error.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
> accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
> invalid.

**Detailed Error Information:**

**Module**     IIS Web Core

**Notification**       BeginRequest

**Handler**    Not yet determined

**Error Code**     0x80070021

**Config Error**       This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

**Config File**    \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\APITeslin\web.config

Config Source:

```
36:   <system.webServer>  
37:     <handlers>  
38:       <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
```

Comment: This is likely to be Windows authentication disabled in IIS, but required in your application's web.config.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS - this configuration section cannot be used at this path (configuration locking?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock)

Comment: @SpaceBison how can i enable Window Authentication in IIS8 ?

Comment: Here is link of my webconfig file.                                       http://icopter.co.uk/Webconfig.txt

Comment: Have you considered using URL rewrite module?

Answer (score 422, accepted):

Got precisely the same error and came to this question. As @SpaceBison mentioned in comments, this answer describes the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12867753/404099. I spotted it too late and it misses some steps. This is what worked for me:

**Windows Server 2012, IIS 8.5**. Should work for other versions too.

- Go to server manager, click add roles and features
- In the roles section choose: Web Server

  - Under Security sub-section choose everything (I excluded digest, IP restrictions and URL authorization as we don't use them)
  - Under Application Development choose .NET Extensibility 4.5, ASP.NET 4.5 and both ISAPI entries
- In the features section choose: NET 3.5, .NET 4.5, ASP.NET 4.5
- In the web server section choose: Web Server (all), Management Tools (IIS Management Console and Management Service), Windows Authentication  - if you are using any of it

Comment: All I had to add was the .NET 4.5 items in the AppDev section and the Features section. The extensibility item also forced the 2 ISAPI entries.

Comment: Finally, a solution to solve my ailments. Thanks, it makes sense, and its simple enough. It always seems to be missing features and roles these days...

Comment: the ServerManager is not available in Windows7 Home, how to fix it?

Comment: @knocte - in Windows 7 you can enter the "Uninstall or change a program" and then hit "Turn Windows features on or off". This is not the same as the Server Manager, but you can install IIS and related features this way.

Comment: WORKED (didn't have to install 3.5), did have to recycle the app pool for it to take effect. (thx)

Comment: Great! It works properly, neither I install .NET3.5.

Comment: Where is the Server Manager? I have a PC with Windows 8 and IIS 8.5

Comment: Worked for me too. But I only need this part "Under Application Development choose .NET Extensibility 4.5, ASP.NET 4.5 and both ISAPI entries". Using Win Server 2016.

Comment: Enabling All Security did fr me

Comment: worked for me, tried the link mentioned (windows 10, VS-19). thanks man

Comment: ASP.NET 4.8 checkbox worked for me per @Bill (under Windows Features -> World Wide Web -> Application Dev Feat)

Answer (score 169):

I got this error while trying to host a WCF service in an empty ASP.NET application. The whole solution was using .NET 4.5 platform, on IIS 8.5 running on Windows 8.1.
The gotcha was to

1. Open up "Turn Windows Features on or off"
2. Go to WCF section under ASP.NET 4.5 advanced services
3. Check HTTP Activation: 
   [image: Screenshot of Windows Features, showing HTTP Activation checked under .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services -> WCF Services]
4. You'll be asked to restart the system.

This should fix HTTP 500.19 errors and other HTTP errors, too.

Comment: @dotnetguy Got the same exact issue and this solved it! Thanks a lot! You really are a .Net guy! :D

Answer (score 59):

I also was getting the same problem but after brain storming with IIS and google for many hours. I found out the solution.
This error is because some settings are disabled in IIS `applicationHost.config`.

Below are the steps to solution:

1. Go to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` and open in notepad
2. Change the following key value present in

   - `<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />` change this value from "Deny" to "Allow"
   - `<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />` 
     change this value from "Deny" to "Allow"

It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. After doing these steps the next error appeared. I could solve it like described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30594003/434742

Comment: is there any side effect on changin this configs?

Answer (score 32):

If you're running IIS on that computer for the first time, you should try running the ASP.NET IIS registration tool (aspnet_regiis.exe).

Here's how to do that:
If you're using .net framework v4, open command prompt as an administrator, and change directory to your .net framework base folder using:

```
CD C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

or, if you're using a 64 bit computer, use:

```
CD C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
```

when you've successfully navigated to the appropriate directory, execute the ASP.NET IIS registration tool using:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

If you're using a different .NET framework version, simply replace `v4.0.30319` with the appropriate folder name.

Comment: I am trying to run two different VS projects on my iis server (virtual machine); one works, one doesn't... The above helped get the first working; is there any reason the 2nd shouldn't work?

Comment: I used this method in the past but aspnet_regiis is no longer supported on Windows 8.1. To register 4.5 use the Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > Information Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features > Check ASP.NET 4.5 and whatever else you might need.

Comment: this needs to be run as Administrator (right click on cmd.exe icon -> run as administrator), and even it if can detect errors during the operation (and produce a log file), it worked for me!

Comment: For IIS 8.5 on Windows 8.1 (or Windows Server 2012) this does not work. I got the following prompt:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -i

Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.33440).
This option is not supported on this version of the operating system.  Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog,  the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool.

Comment: Thanks!! It works for me with IIS 10 and Windows 10 :)

Answer (score 28):

I solved this by doing the following:

```
WebServer(ISS)->WebServer->Application Development
add .NET Extensibility 3.5
add .NET Extensibility 4.5
add ASP.NET 4.5
add ISAPI Extensions
add ISAPI Filters
```

[image]

Comment: Newer OSs like Windows 11 try checking box "ASP.NET 4.8"

Answer (score 11):

On Windows 8.1, IIS 8.5 the solution for me was to register 4.5 from the control panel:

Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off > Information Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application Development Features > Select ASP.NET 4.5

Click OK.

Comment: Under Windows 10 choices were 'ASP', ASP.NET.35.', and 'ASP.NET 4.6'. Checking 4.6 worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the most concise and easy-to-understand answer.

Answer (score 8):

As the error indicates:

> This happens when the section is locked at a parent level.

To unlock the section you can use [appcmd.exe](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) and execute the following command:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe unlock config -section:system.webServer/handlers -commitpath:apphost
```

For more information on about section locking and what a parent configuration context is refer to [IIS documentation](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration).

Answer (score 8):

On Windows **8.1 or 10** include the .Net framework 4.5 or above as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If it is windows 10 then open the powershell as admin and run the following command:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45
```

Answer (score 4):

In our case, we struggled with this error for quite some days. It turns out that in control panel, programs, turn windows features on or off.

We selected Internet Information Services, world wide web services, Application development features and there we check the set of features associated with our development environment. For example: ASP.NET 4.6. .NET Extensibility 4.6, etc.

It works!

Answer (score 3):

Try unlocking the relevant IIS (7.5) configuration settings at server level, as follows:

1. Open **IIS Manager**
2. **Select the server** in the Connections pane
3. Open **Configuration Editor** in the main pane
4. In the Sections drop down, select the section to unlock, e.g. **system.webServer > defaultPath**
5. Click **Unlock Attribute** in the right pane
6. Repeat for any other settings which you need to unlock
7. Restart IIS (optional) - Select the server in the Conncetions pane, click Restart in the Actions pane

Comment: This is almost helpful but on IIS 7 there is no "defaultPath" under system.webServer

Comment: By that he means if you are looking to update Windows Authentication then you will find it in the path system.webServer -> Security -> Authentication.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, there were rules for IIS [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module but I didn't have that module installed. You should check your web.config if there are any modules included but not installed.

Comment: Just installed everything else needed, but still not got it to work. Then, I just installed the URL Rewrite module, and got it working! Thanks!

Comment: If URL Rewrite module is missing, the error code won't be 0x80070021.

Answer (score 1):

Your web.config describes that you're using **forms authentication** - make sure you enable forms authentication and *disable* anonymous authentication in IIS under the Authentication menu, for the website that is running in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

I got Error Code 0x80070021 when migrating IIS7 to IIS 10 in a Windows 2016 environment. The below step helped me to fix it, from [*Troubleshooting HTTP 500.19 errors in IIS 7*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/webtopics/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7).

Manually change the value from "Deny" to "Allow" for `overrideModeDefault` in your server's applicationHost Config:

File Location:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\ applicationHost.config
```

Under `<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">`, set the following values:

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, we're using Amazon Web Services and so we are looking to use scripts and programs to get through this problem.  So I have been on the hunt for a command line tool.  So first I tried the trick of running

`c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

but because I'm running a cloud based Windows Server 2012 it complained

`This option is not supported on this version of the operating system. Administrators should instead install/uninstall ASP.NET 4.5 with IIS8 using the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" dialog, the Server Manager management tool, or the dism.exe command line tool. For more details please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=216771.`

and I Googled and found the official [Microsoft Support Page KB2736284](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2736284).  So there is a command line tool `dism.exe`.  So I tried the following

`dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45`

but it complained and gave a list of featurenames to try, so I tried them one by one and I tested my WebAPI webpage after each and it worked after the bottom one in the list.

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ISAPIFilter 
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ISAPIExtensions 
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-NetFxExtensibility45
```

And so now I can browse to my WebAPI site and see the API information.  That should help a few people.  [However, I am not out of the woods totally myself yet and I cannot reach the website from outside the box.   Still working on it.]

Also, I did some earlier steps following other people responses.  I can confirm that the following Feature Delegation needs to be change (though I'd like to find a command line tool for these).

```
In Feature delegation

Change 
'Handler Mappings' from Read Only to Read/Write

Change 
'Modules' from Read Only to Read/Write

Change 
'SSL Settings' from Read Only to Read/Write
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this today on a Windows 2016 Core server I resolved the issue by ensuring the components were installed as mentioned by [GIOESCOM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5445681/gioescom) and then I repaired the SDK's in my case for .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5 and .NET 6 which resolved the issue and the ASP.NET 4.7.2 MVC web app worked.

Answer (score -1):

Please `<staticContent />` line and erased it from the web.config.

Answer (score -1):

Check if IIS server installed the URL rewrite feature. 
If it is not installed then make sure your web.config file don't have the URL rewrite related configuration

```
<!-- Make sure don't have below config, if server have not installed url rewrite feature. -->
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Fail bad requests">
      <match url=".*"/> ...
```

Some time we copied the config from legacy server and straight away deploy to brand new server, then we may encounter such kind of  500 issue.

Comment: If URL Rewrite is missing, the error code won't be 0x80070021.

Answer (score -1):

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault=”Deny”)

From older IIS and server

We may encounter the following error when we want to run our application on IIS 10 built on the new Microsoft Windows Server 2016.

HTTP Error 500.19 – Internal Server Error

The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault=”Deny”), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode=”Deny” or the legacy allowOverride=”false
The solution is very simple.

Follow the C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config file path from your computer. Change the overrideModeDefault=”Deny” part in the applicationHost config file to “Allow”. Then when you restart IIS, the problem will be fixed.

Comment: This repeats existing solutions.

Answer (score -4):

The solution that worked for me was to delete my current Web.config and add a new one. That solved the problem for me

Comment: Resigning from my job is easier than creating a new web.config. Never ever try to do so.