# Windows 7 IIS Manager missing "Add Roles and Features" option

Tags: windows, iis, server, roles

I'm trying to follow [the instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021) to resolve an 500.19 error. However, I'm missing the "Add Roles and Features" option.

This is what my UI looks like:

[image]

Where is the Add Roles option?

Comment: Server Manager is different from IIS manager.

Comment: How do I access the Server Manager?

Answer (score 0):

1) Access Server Manager by typing in "ServerManager" in the Start menu. If it doesn't appear, search for ServerManager.msc

2) In Server Manager, under Roles, right-click on Web Server (IIS) to add roles.

Comment: I didn't find any results for either of those

Comment: Ah. Your version of Windows not Windows Server?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 you'll do it like this:

- goto `Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off`
- wait until the tree view is build
- expand `Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features`
- enable whatever you need

done!