# HTTP Error 500.19 - Error Code 0x80070021

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

**Background:** Trying to debug WebForms application and get authenticated windows user from AD,

On F5 I get greeted with this amazing page.

**Module**
   WindowsAuthenticationModule

**Notification**
   AuthenticateRequest

**Handler**
   ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0

**Error Code**
   0x80070021

**Config Error**
   This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

[image: onDebug]

**Config Source:**

```
   81:         <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
   82:         <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
   83:         <basicAuthentication enabled="false"
```

My Web.config(JustDifferentNames)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    <!--<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
    <section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="false" />
    <add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />
    <add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />-->
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=idea-pc;Initial Catalog=componentnameNumber;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>-->
    <add name="DBComponent1" connectionString="Data Source=idea-pc;Initial Catalog=comp2;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="DBComponent2" connectionString="Data Source=idea-pc;Initial Catalog=comp3;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="DBComponent3" connectionString="Data Source=idea-pc;Initial Catalog=comp4;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="DBComponent4" connectionString="Data Source=idea-pc;Initial Catalog=comp5;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MyProj-20160209113257.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MyProjectEvents-20160209113257;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
        <identity impersonate="false"/>
        <authorization>
           <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <!--</system.web>-->
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <!--
        ASP.NET Membership Profile is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager>
      <!--
          ASP.NET Membership Role is disabled in this template. Please visit the following link http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301889 to learn about the ASP.NET Membership support in this template
        -->
      <providers>
        <clear/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <!--
            If you are deploying to a cloud environment that has multiple web server instances,
            you should change session state mode from "InProc" to "Custom". In addition,
            change the connection string named "DefaultConnection" to connect to an instance
            of SQL Server (including SQL Azure and SQL  Compact) instead of to SQL Server Express.
      -->
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="30" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"/>
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false"
                             realm=""
                             defaultLogonDomain="TestDomain"/>
      </authentication>
    </security>



    <modules>
      <!--<remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>-->
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Looked around checked my settings and I found that I dont have Win Auth under my
 IIS -> World Wide Web Services -> Security

[image]

Neither do i have it here (Even after disabling anonymous auth)

[image]

What am i missing to check ? or do for that matter, **im still a noob**.

Edit:

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021

Comment: @JanuaryMmako I think i have tried most of the things on that post. I have been fighting this issue for 6-7 hours, trying to figure out how it works. Under Application dev i have done what is posted on that post. I will update question with more information to clearify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows edition you used is a low end one, which does not even support Windows authentication.

You will have to upgrade to a high end edition such as Professional.

Comment: Guess im coding without building.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is editing the appplicationhost.config file.
Changed under the Authentication node:
from DENY to ALLOW on the following elements:

```
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately nobody give neither an upvote nor a comment but this is the most useful answer for this question, this helped me a lot, not once but multiple times, thank you so much brother.