# Setup NuGet.Server doesn't run the app due to Locking

Tags: nuget, nuget-server

I've followed the simple steps on here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server

But, then my application fails to run with this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [HTTP Error 500.19 and error code : 0x80070021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021) and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2010/03/08/troubleshooting-http-500-19-errors-in-iis-7/ (search on the 80070021 error in the latter). I don't think it's specific to NuGet.Server at all.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by enabling more IIS options from Turn Windows Features on/off.