# Hosting website on Azure VM - Windows Server 2016

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis

I am trying to host my website on Azure VM (OS is Windows Server 2016) and IIS 10.0. So here is what i did.

1. Installed iis using 
    **server Manager** -> Add roles and features ...
2. Installed database Server (MySql) & .Net Framework 4x was already there.
3. Copied asp.net project on a physical path
4. Open IIS Manager -> Right-click Sites folder -> Add website
5. Gave site name, physical path and changed port to 93
6. Now whenever i try to browse, it gives me following error

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> ...
>
> Error Code       0x80070021 Config Error     This configuration section
>   cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked
>   at a parent level. Locking is either by default
>   (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with
>   overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false". Config File
>   \?\C:\project.Web\web.config
>
> Config Source:    41:       42:         43:

I have looked up this code in microsoft and this is what they had to say

[image]

Still I am not sure if this is the real problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yay! I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021) by Ilia Barahovski

Answer (score 0):

So I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021)

Windows Server 2016, IIS 10.0

- Server Manager -> Add roles and features
- In the roles section choose: Web Server
  Under Security sub-section choose everything (i also excluded digest, IP restrictions and URL authorization)
  Under Application Development choose .NET Extensibility 4.5, ASP.NET 4.5 and both ISAPI entries
- In the features section choose: .NET 4.5, ASP.NET 4.5