# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - Deploying an umbraco website on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to deploy my Umbraco website on IIS, but getting the error as in the below snapshot. I have also given the full access to IIS\IUSRS user to the folder where the code resides.

Please let me know, what else could be done to resolve the issue.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021

Comment: Use Jexus Manager, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/local-iis.html and it should report which line the error comes from and then the solution would be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked if the URL Rewrite module is installed? I've found 99% of the time, 500.19 errors are due to config for a missing module.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, installing this package, did help resolve the issue

Comment: This gets me every time