# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error Error Code 0x80070021

Tags: iis

I've installed an IIS server on windows 8 and plublished my first site, this is the error I get. Any help would be appreciated.

> Detailed Error Information:
>
> Module    IIS Web Core
>
> Notification    BeginRequest
>
> Handler    Not yet determined
>
> Error Code    0x80070021

```
Config Error
   This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

Config File
   \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ContractorScoping\web.config

Requested URL
   http://localhost:80/ContractorScoping

Physical Path
   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ContractorScoping

Logon Method
   Not yet determined

Logon User
   Not yet determined

```
Config Source:
   68:     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
   69:     <modules>
   70:       <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
```

Line 69 is the one highlighted in red

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 500.19 and error code : 0x80070021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schoolboy error, forgot to install asp.net on the server

Comment: Thanks for this answer - this saved me potential hours of red herring hunting around unlocking configuration elements (as directed by Microsoft)

Comment: Wasted about 20 mins figuring this out, before finding this post. Else would have probably spent 20 hours. Thank you 

Answer (score 4):

This error comes due to missing IIS Packages. I solved the error with doing these steps:

1. Click "Start button"
2. in the search box, enter "Turn windows features on or off"
3. in the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"
4. Click: "World Wide Web Services"
5. Click: "Application Development Features"
6. Check (enable) the features. I checked all but CGI.