# HTTP Error 500.19. How to set overrideMode="Allow" on web.config?

Tags: iis-10

I receive this error on IIS 10

```
Module         AnonymousAuthenticationModule
Notification   AuthenticateRequest
Handler        ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
Error Code     0x80070021
Config Error   This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

How to allow overrideMode on IIS 10 Web.Config?

This recipe with applicationHost.config don't working https://docs.supportpal.com/current/Troubleshoot+IIS+Configuration+Option+Cannot+Be+Used

Feature Delegation from this from this topic [Config Error: This configuration section cannot be used at this path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/config-error-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path?page=2&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) is absent

Of course, all IIS future added, this site don't use ASP.NET, ASP only. I need only add allow overriding in root web config, how to do this?

Comment: That's impossible as no one should be able to unlock sections from `web.config` (that will be a security black hole).

Comment: @LexLi, Why this is security black hole? For example whole site has anonymous AU, but in some site subfolder I want to delete anonymous AU.

Comment: Some configurations can only be configured in applicationhost. You can set **overrideModeDefault="Allow"** in <configSections> of applicationhost.config.

Answer (score 0):

[This may be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52586060/http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-error-code-0x80070021)

In **Windows features** -> IIS -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Development Features -> Enable ALL packages