# Why deploying and then running asmx service throws 500 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, asmx

I have a `webservice` in `asmx`. I am hosting it to the `IIS 7.0` in the `Default Web Site` but it throws an error upon browsing.

> HTTP Error 500.19 with this code 0x80070021

Also, upon expanding the folder in IIS it doesn't show `web.config` and `.asmx`file even it's there right in the folder.

[image]

Folder internal view:

[image: Image 2]

Webservice Code:

```
namespace Plant_WebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for EngineeringData
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class EngineeringData : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public bool InsertEngineeringData(string FunctionalLocation, string EqptType, string WINFileNo, string ComponentTagNo)
        {
            bool Status = false;

            EngineeringDataDAL EngineeringDataDAL = new Vail_PlantWebApi.EngineeringDataDAL();

            Status = EngineeringDataDAL.InsertEngineeringData(FunctionalLocation, EqptType, WINFileNo, ComponentTagNo);

            return Status;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please post your webservice code.

Comment: sure 1 min .. pasting

Comment: done, question updated

Comment: Duplicate Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021

Comment: @KevinShah: have you checked?

Comment: yes I have checked but have you checked comment added by @pbachman?

Comment: Please show the entire error page. 500.19 usually indicates the your `web.config` contains something wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 500.19 and error code : 0x80070021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021)