# can some help me to solve the 0x80070021 error

Tags: iis

I am new to iis, when I try to access the site, I get the following error：

```
Module
IIS Web Core

Notification
BeginRequest

Handler
Not yet determined

Error Code
0x80070021
```

I tried to search for similar problems through Google, and tried the steps in the link below, but without success.

[HTTP Error 500.19 and error code : 0x80070021](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048486/http-error-500-19-and-error-code-0x80070021)

Can some one help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description and error mesage, it seems something wrong with your web.config.

The 0x80070021 error occurs if the specified portion of the IIS configuration file is locked at a higher configuration level.

I suggest you could refer to below article to know how to unlock the configuration.

[How to Use Locking in IIS 7.0 Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-for-security/how-to-use-locking-in-iis-configuration)